# How we can create a webservice with authentication in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, webservice-client

I want to create webservices in laravel with authentication check for accessing the different endpoints and option to create application for the webservice usage like generating API key, secret etc.

Comment: Great. What have you tried?

Comment: check `laravel passport` in documents. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will try passport.

Comment: jwt authentication is another option available

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel Passport` is where you can look at.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport